# Select records where two arrays are not equal regardless of the order of the array elements in PySpark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to select records where two arrays are not equal regardless of the order of the array elements using PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_sort to sort the arrays first:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.filter(F.array_sort(F.col('array1')) != F.array_sort(F.col('array2')))
```